# css width no show right when use animate jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have one div in position fixed and use animate function of jquery for grow this div in this position and into of this hide div i have other divs for show informations in this case mobile_title

```
<style>

#mobile_col_left
{
  position:fixed;
  float:left;
  width:5%;
  height:150%;
  background-color:#000;
  z-index:9999999;
}


#mobile_menu_title
{
  position:relative;
  width:97%;
  height:38px;
  line-height:38px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding-legt:1%;
  font-family:Arial;
  color:#000;
  font-size:15px;
}

</style>



$("#mobile_col_left").animate({ width: '65%' }, "slow");
```

mobile_col load inside mobile_menu_title , when i load the mobile_col start with 5% , the people can see this with this width , when i activate the animation the div grow to 65% but inside of div , the div called mobile_menu_title , no grow also to the 97% , always stay width other size

The question it´s why no grow the div called mobile_title , when i supose have increase and cover all size of the other div when grow , but no happen this

Thank´s for the help

Comment: is this a typo : `position:fized;`

Comment: It's hard to understand ur English for me sorry

Comment: Sorry it´s position relative

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear.

Just a thing to say that position relative in the parent doesn't do anything for fixed positioned child, you can start thinking that way.

Comment: Yes right i see when the div it´s hide and show after no happend nothing with the div relative